# How to share object for all app's activities

Tags: java, android, singleton, android-animation, android-button

I have an animation that I want to apply on every button in my app. So I don't want to call AnimationUtils.loadAnimation() in every activity onCreate method. I would like to call this method only one time when the app is launched to initialize my animation object, and then get it (with a getter) in my different activities.
I'm new in Android programming, I was planning to use a Singleton pattern but it looks like to be "unsafe" in Android related to this article and other Stackoverflow pages. (https://programmerr47.medium.com/singletons-in-android-63ddf972a7e7)

Is there anyway to create my Animation at app launching and share it between every activity ?  And does it worth to do some optimization ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest extending the android `Button`/`AppCompatButton` class, adding the functionality you want to the extended class and using that button everywhere in your app much easier that way and probably the most correct way,

For example:

**AnimatedButton.java:**

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;

public class AnimatedButton extends androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton {
    public AnimatedButton(Context context) {
        super(context);
        createAnimation();
    }

    public AnimatedButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public AnimatedButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    private void createAnimation() {
        // here create the animation and call
        // setAnimation([YOUR_ANIMATION_HERE]);
        // now you can simply call customButton.animate();
        // from anywhere in the code that uses the button and it should work
    }
}
```

In your xml where you want to use the button:

```
<com.example.myapplication.AnimatedButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_animate"
            android:layout_width="180dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:text="Animate" />
```

Comment: Glad to help. Please do give an upvote and mark the question as solved if it is. Happy coding.